# Uncaught ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined with spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering package

Tags: reactjs, laravel, single-page-application, server-side-rendering, meta-tags

I am using Reactjs with Laravel 7. Everything works fine except the dynamic meta tags on each page of my website was not updating when API request is sent in the backend. I did use the *react-helmet* package but it did not update the meta tags. I also used the Laravel *butschster/LaravelMetaTags* package, which also did not solve the issue.

I decided to use the ***spatie/laravel-server-side-rendering*** and add SSR to my application. Here is the implementation I have done so far.

**index.blade.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<meta>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>{{ config('custom.title') }}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{{ config('custom.description') }}"/>

  {{--
default meta tags, it should be updated with API request
--}}
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ config('custom.title') }}"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{ config('custom.description') }}"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
  <meta property="og:url" content="{{url()->current()}}"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content=""/>
  <link rel="canonical" href="{{url()->current()}}"/>
</head>
<body>

  {!! ssr('build/js/server.js')
     ->fallback('<div id="frontend"></div>')
     ->render()!!}

<script src="{{ asset(mix('build/js/client.js')) }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset(mix('build/js/server.js')) }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';

import FrontApp from './FrontApp';

const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  <div id="frontend">
    <h1>Testing</h1>//this is not displayed at all.
  </div>
);

dispatch(html);//this gives error.
```

**client.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import FrontApp from './App';//this is the main App.

if (document.getElementById('frontend')) {
  render(<App/>, document.getElementById('frontend'));
}
```

Let me describe a bit more about the app:
It is a SPA and the `index.blade.php` is loaded only for the first time. The rest of the pages are using HTTP requests. What I want is to update the meta tags when the HTTP request is sent from client to server.

**Current Error:**
I get a console error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: dispatch is not defined` when loading my app for the first time. It seems the SSR server is not working at all.

For now, I don't know why the `dispatch` method is not working and it uses the fallback div (i.e. `->fallback('<div id="frontend"></div>'`)).

Please help me with this issue and the dynamic meta tags. Any alternative solution is also welcomed. Thanks.